# Manipulating columns in txt file using Python

Tags: python, sql, pycharm

I have been trying to create a script for this task for a while now but whatever direction i go in, i always find a dead end so here i am looking for help. Even though this may seem like a simple task, i'm fairly new to Python and the way everything works so any help would be greatly appreciated.

[File Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuxT9.png)

In this picture we can see five labelled columns. The idea of the script would be to sum the 'Units' column, and as well as this, multiply the 'Unit' Column by the 'Dealer Price' to give us a revenue.  I also want to group this by 'Consumer Country' and 'Currency Code'

I have written an SQL query to help:

```
SELECT SUM(Units*Dealer_Price)
SUM(Units)
Consumer_Country,
Currency Code
FROM Sales File
GROUP BY Consumer_Country, Currency_Code
```

I have this so far ( Thanks to @ParvBanks & @Martin Frodl)

```
df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv', Header=None, encoding='utf-8', sep='\t')
df['Revenue'] = df['Units'] * df['Dealer Price']
df = df.groupby(['Consumer Country', 'Currency Code']).sum()
df = df[['Revenue', 'Units']]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Use pandas lib to load the file and make the operations you need

Comment: With pandas you will be able to use SQL queries.

Comment: This does not tell us what type of file you're trying to load into the dataframe? Is it a CSV file or an excel?

Comment: @ParvBanks sorry, this is a txt file

Comment: Can you also paste a sample of the text file so that we can copy and test it. There are other columns with missing headers, so the solutions might not be accurate. Snapshots don't help much :)

Comment: @ParvBanks Excel

Comment: @ParvBanks sorry i'm new to Stack as you can see, how i do copy some data from the spreadsheet so it shows in tabular form

Comment: @ParvBanks My data is also tab delimited so will not allow me to paste data a clear neat tabular form

Comment: ok, understood, so it's a tab delimited csv text file. You can paste how it looks after you have imported to the dataframe. 

df = pd.read_csv('file', sep='\t')

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['Revenue'] = df['Units'] * df['Dealer Price']
df = df.groupby(['Consumer Country', 'Currency Code']).sum()
df = df[['Revenue', 'Units']]
```